# Python bpy hdri download

Tags: python, celery, blender, bpy

I translated my script written in `bpy` to work with `celery`, during startup I get logs

> `Fra:1 Mem:123.06M (Peak 171.35M) | Time:00:00.28 | Mem:17.02M, Peak:17.02M | Scene, View Layer | Updating Images | Loading machine_shop_01_2k.exr`

This `hdri` is sewn into the blend extension file that I use

The download does not seem to be going at all, tell me if this could be related to the transition to celery and what solutions I can use

I tried to change the `hdri` to my own, and tried to disable the hdri update altogether, but none of this helped

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.